# Javascript - why is my value undefined when passed as an argument through a function

Tags: javascript, parameters, arguments, undefined

I have written a function that calls a zipcode API to retrieve the address when entering a ZIP code. (Note: it's a Dutch application and a Dutch zipcode consists of 4 numbers and 2 letters.)

This is the function:

```
function zipcodeApiCall(zipcodeNum, zipcodeAlfa)
{
    console.log(zipcodeNum);
    if(zipcodeNum.length == 4 && zipcodeAlfa.length == 2)
    {
        //some code to call the API that returns some data
    }
}

//Call the function
var zipcodeNum = $("#zipcodeNum").val(); //Retrieve val from input field
var result = zipcodeApiCall(zipcodeNum, 'KK');
```

The problem is that I get the error that zipcodeNum is undefined when retrieving its length. The output of:

```
console.log(zipcodeNum);
```

for zipcode numbers 1312 is two lines:

```
1312
undefined
```

Which gives me the error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'. Why does this happen?

What's also strange is that when I retrieve the value of zipcodeNum inside the function, like so:

```
function zipcodeApiCall()
{
    var zipcodeNum = $("#zipcodeNum").val(); //Retrieve val from input field
    var zipcodeAlfa = 'KK';
    console.log(zipcodeNum);
    if(zipcodeNum.length == 4 && zipcodeAlfa.length == 2)
    {
        //some code to call the API that returns some data
    }
}
var result = zipcodeApiCall();
```

the code executes fine and I don't get any errors.

Comment: Where is the actual invocation of the function? It sounds like undefined is actually being passed through.

A codepen/plunkr etc. would be useful.

Comment: Show us where you call `zipcodeApiCall`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that line, I've edited my code now

Comment: where's the second console.log line coming from?  You've only shown one in your code.

Comment: So `$("#zipcodeNum").val()` is yielding `undefined`? Sounds like a duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/1048572) then